# Adding a value to an existing key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list:

```
Marks =[
    [12345,75,'English'],
    [23452,83,'Physics'],
    [23560,81,'Statistics'],
    [23415,61,'Computer'],
    [23459,90,'Physics'],
    [12345,75,'Computer'],
    [23452,100,'Statistics']
]
```

and I want to make a dictionary where the class name is the key and the two
numbers are the values.
I can make the initial dictionary like this:

```
for i in list1:
    dict1[i[2]]=i[0],i[1]
```

But when I print the dictionary, only one of each of the pairs of numbers associated is printed. I'm looking for a result like:

```
{ 
  'English' : [[12345,75]],
  'Physics' : [[23452,83], [23459,90]],
  'Statistics' : [[23560,81], [23452,100]],
  'Computer' : [[23415,61], [12345,75]]
}
```

Is there any way I can extend the values associated with a key?

I tried:

```
if i[2] in dict1:
    dict1.extend
```

Comment: `print( {i[-1]: i[:2] for i in Marks} )` ?

Comment: The issue that I'm having is that there would be two sets of tuples for the same course. It should be 'Statistics: [23560, 81], [23452, 100]. And I can add the first set of numbers, but not hte second

Comment: @user10613120 It's a good idea to include an example of the output you're looking for. I've edited in an example.

Comment: {'Computer': [12345, 75], [23145, 65] ,
 'English': [12345, 75],
 'Physics': [23459, 90], [12345,67],
 'Statistics': [23452, 100], [98765,30]}

Answer (score 2):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

Marks = [[12345,75,'English'], [23452,83,'Physics'], [23560,81,'Statistics'], [23415,61,'Computer'], [23459,90,'Physics'], [12345,75,'Computer'], [23452,100,'Statistics']]

result = defaultdict(list)
for i in Marks:
    result[i[-1]].append(i[:2])
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Statistics': [[23560, 81], [23452, 100]], 'Physics': [[23452, 83], [23459, 90]], 'Computer': [[23415, 61], [12345, 75]], 'English': [[12345, 75]]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single value for a key in your dictionary. But you could save the two values as either a list or a tuple like so:

```
for i in list1:
    dict1[i[2]]=i[0:1]
```

or

```
for i in list1:
    dict1[i[2]]=(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: but there are two sets of two numbers associated with each course. My poor explanation, but that's the issue that I'm having. It should be 'Statistics: [23560, 81], [23452, 100]

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehensions to achieve that easily:

```
>>> Marks = [[12345,75,'English'], [23452,83,'Physics'], [23560,81,'Statistics'], [23415,61,'Computer'], [23459,90,'Physics'], [12345,75,'Computer'], [23452,100,'Statistics']]
>>> d = { m[2]: [m[0], m[1]] for m in Marks }
>>> d
{'English': [12345, 75], 'Physics': [23459, 90], 'Statistics': [23452, 100], 'Computer': [12345, 75]}
>>>
```

EDIT: This will create the dictionary taking into account those repeated keys.

```
d = {}
for mark in Marks:
     if not mark[2] in d:
             d[mark[2]] = [[mark[0], mark[1]]]
     else:
             d[mark[2]] += [[mark[0], mark[1]]]
```

The dictionary will end up with this shape:

```
>>> d
{'English': [[12345, 75]], 'Physics': [[23452, 83], [23459, 90]], 'Statistics': [[23560, 81], [23452, 100]], 'Computer': [[23415, 61], [12345, 75]]}
>>>
```

Comment: but there are two sets of two numbers associated with each course. My poor explanation, but that's the issue that I'm having. It should be 'Statistics: [23560, 81], [23452, 100]

Comment: Sorry. I completely missed that detail. I will try to update my example.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was trying to do with either extending or adding to the value. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look on Rakesh's answer. It is a better and more Pythonic way of achieving the same result.